# Replace Standard View with VF Page in Agent Console - Links not working

Tags: visualforce, javascript, service-cloud-console, servicecloud, view

We wish to use the agent console as it has many benefits but to meet some requirements we need to replace the standard View Page with a Visualforce page but we used the Standard Controller and Apex Detail tag to maintain UI fluidity. See VF code below:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Customer" subtitle="{!Account.Name}"/>    
<chatter:feedWithFollowers entityId="{!Account.Id}" />    
<apex:detail subject="{!Account.Id}" relatedList="true" title="false" inlineEdit="true"/> 
</apex:page>
```

When I view this page outside the service console, everything works perfectly (as you would imagine). But as soon as I view an account in Service Console, we notice there are two "bugs":

1. The hyperlinks in the related list do not work.
2. The Interaction Log
   "Related To" drop down no longer pre-populates, and maintains the
   value "000000000000000".

Does anyone have any solutions for either problem? From my understanding the repaced VF page breaks the Javascript that runs in the console to hijack hyperlinks etc to behave in a specific way.